# Can the model object for a learner be exported with joblib?

Tags: python, orange

I'm evaluating orange as a potential solution to helping new entrants into data science to get started. I would like to have them save out model objects created from different algorithms as pkl files similar to how it is done in scikit-learn with joblib or pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what "exported with joblib" refers to, but you can save trained Orange models by pickling them, or with Save Classifier widget if you are using the GUI.